# Python Inheritence Subclass(ing)

Tags: python, inheritance, subclassing

Given a parent class 'A'

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def methodA():
        # do something
```

What is the difference between making a subclass 'B' among the below options

Option 1

```
class B(A):
    def methodB():
        # do something
```

Option 2

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        A.__init__(self, a, b)
    def methodB():
        # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        A.__init__(self, a, b)
    def methodB():
        pass

class C(A):
    def methodB():
        pass

b = B(1,2)
c = C(1,2)
print b.a == c.a # True
print b.b == c.b # True
```

In both class instantiation, **init** under class A will be ran only once.
so no, there is nothing significantly different.
`class B` is not clean IMO and poses no real purpose at all. It will be ran anyways.

If you wish to do something different in class B init, then yes, you can use this code.

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        A.__init__(self, a+1, b+1)
    def methodB():
        pass
```